# How to get latitude and longitude lines in world wind?

Tags: latitude-longitude, worldwind

can some body please tell me how to draw lines on the earth in `WorldWind`.

i want to draw latitude and longitude line on the surface of globe visible ?

Comment: Can you draw anything at all? What are you able to do? Post some code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the graticule layer:

```
   try {
       graticuleLayer = (Layer) LatLonGraticuleLayer.class.newInstance();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Can't get a graticule layer " + e);
   }
   if (graticuleLayer != null) {
       graticuleLayer.setEnabled(true);
   }
```